# Adding Data Frame to mxd in c# standalone application

Tags: arcobjects, c#, mxd

I am writing a stand-alone application in c# (using vs2010). I have ArcGis Desktop license.
I only need to insert a new data frame in an mxd file and save this mxd.

I create MxDocument coclass. Then get IMxDocument interface from that. Then i use its "Maps" property which return me IMaps interface. From that I call its method Add() to add a new dataframe.

Code:

```
Dim pDocClassOut As MxDocumentClas = New MxDocumentClass()
Dim appl As IApplication = TryCast(pDocClassOut.Parent, IApplication)
Dim mxDoc As IMxDocument = TryCast(appl.Document, IMxDocument)
Dim maps As IMaps = CType(mxDoc.Maps, IMaps)
Dim pMap1 As IMap = New MapClass
pMap1.Name = "XYZ"
maps.Add(pMap1)

mxDoc.UpdateContents()
appl.SaveDocument()
appl.SaveAsDocument("E:\DEV EnGIS\Untitled.mxd")
appl.Shutdown()
```

Why does this simple code not work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcGIS Engine, then according to the help file this interface will not work because it is for desktop only

Have a look at this link:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMaps_Interface/00120000097v000000/

If you are developing for desktop then try the create method.